# Extending textured gameObject smoothly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating simple game and I need to create extending cylinder. I know how to normally do it - by changing objects pivot point and scaling it up, but now I have texture on it and I don't want it to stretch.

I fought about adding small segments to the end of the cylinder when it has to grow, but this wont work smooth and might affect performance. Do you know any solution to this?

This the rope texture that I'm using right now(but it might change in the future):

Before scaling

[image]

After scaling

[image]

Comment: What does the texture look like before and after scale? Edit your question with that(images).

Comment: @Programmer I updated the post

Comment: before and after images not one image.

Comment: @Programmer updated

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41613  Here's a "free version" but it's coding: https://github.com/Dsphar/Cube_Texture_Auto_Repeat_Unity/blob/master/ReCalcCubeTexture.cs    Maybe also possible with shaders. BUT. While you test these, also wait for a better/complete answer (hopefully involving some mapping, maybe shader code... I'd love to see something like that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want it to stretch

This is not easy to accomplish but it is possible.

You have two ways to do this.

**1**.One is to procedurally generate the rope mesh and assign material real-time. This is complicated for beginners. Can't help on this one.

**2**.Another solution that doesn't require mesh procedurally mesh generation. Change the tiles while the Object is changing size.

For this to work, your texture must be tileable. You can't just use any random texture online. Also, you need a normal map to actually make it look like a rope. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNirGFKIW9E) for making a rope texture with normal map in Maya. There are other parts of the video you have to watch too.

Select the texture, change `Texture Type` to `Texture`, change `Wrap Mode` to `Repeat` then click **Apply**.

Get the `MeshRenderer` of the `Mesh` then get `Material` of the 3D Object from the  `MeshRenderer`.Use `ropeMat.SetTextureScale` to change the the tile of the texture. For example, when changing the `xTile` and `yTile` value of the code below, the texture of the Mesh will be tiled.

```
public float xTile, yTile;
public GameObject rope;
Material ropeMat;

void Start()
{
    ropeMat = rope.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
}

void Update()
{
    ropeMat.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", new Vector2(xTile, yTile));
}
```

Now, you have to find a way to map the `xTile` and `yTile` values to the size of the `Mesh`.  It's not simple. [Here](http://ericeastwood.com/blog/20/texture-tiling-based-on-object-sizescale-in-unity) is complete method to calculate what value `xTile` and `yTile` should be when re-sizing the mesh/rope.

Comment: Thanks! I think it will work great for me, I will try it out as soon as I can.

Comment: @clone I tested the code I linked in the answer and it seems to work. You can just used it directly. The only thing remaining is making a tileable color and normal map.

Comment: I have a little bit of trouble calculating value of `xTile` and `yTile`. I'm basically using `void UpdateTiling()` form linked script and it partly works, but it scalses texture on wrong axis (when i scale it on y axis nothing happens, but on z axis it tiles texture as it should when scaling on y).  Also I don't know how can I find `planeSizeX = 10f` and `planeSizeZ = 10f` for my cilinder. I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Ok nevermind i fixed the wrong axis problem, now I need help with finding  `planeSizeX = 10f` and `planeSizeZ = 10f` and also `textureToMeshZ = 2f`

Comment: @clone On that website, it says that A Unity plane is 10 units x 10 units. Create a simple Plane in Unity then compare it to the original size of your rope. That will let you know the approx number to use for `planeSizeX` and `planeSizeZ`. For `textureToMeshZ`, experiment with it and see what work well for you.

Comment: Ok everything works now, but I don't understand what exactly is `planeSizeY`. Is it just the number of planes that my object is taking?

Comment: @clone There is no `planeSizeY` in the code I linked. There are only `planeSizeX` and `planeSizeZ`. Don't forget to tick this answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Yes I meant `planeSizeZ` and `planeSizeX`, I wrote Y because for my case I use only Y axis because it will be resized only on this axis.